# Why are underscores not allowed in usernames in some distros (Debian for example)

Tags: users

So why has the underscore been considered a bad character for user names in Debian (and possibly other distributions) while it has been removed from `adduser`'s NAME_REGEX in Ubuntu?

Comment: Debian has set the underscore as a requirement for usernames who are related with packages. https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/upgrading-checklist.html#version-4-5-0

Answer (score 7):

POSIX [specifies](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_426) the usage of a portable [set](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_276) of characters for user and group names.
`_ - .` are allowed characters, `NAME_REGEX` checks if the username does only contain specified characters. The distribution developers define, if further characters are denied. Ubuntu, for example, does forbid the use of `.` by default.

Adding this restriction avoids interference with other system tools, which may interpret special characters. Think of the variable `$PATH`, when you have a user with the name `my:user` and add your home directory to `$PATH`:

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:`**`/home/my:user/bin`**

The directories `/home/my` and `user/bin` would (probably) not exist. Further, `/etc/passwd` would have two `:` more than needed.

**Edit:**
Debian's `adduser` (version 3.110) uses `/^[_.A-Za-z0-9][-\@_.A-Za-z0-9]*\$?$/` for checking usernames, `_` **is** allowed as long as `NAME_REGEX` does not forbid it.

Comment: But the question was about `_` not `:`...

Comment: Isn't the @ also allowed in posix, at least according to adduser

Comment: And yeah while that explains why you shouldn't allow : it doesn't explain why _ is bad.

Comment: `_` is allowed by default, see the edit. I gave an example of the forbidden character `:` to show the possible problems with it.

Comment: @Sam, @ is not allowed in POSIX, see https://askubuntu.com/a/405668/13482

Answer (score 3):

A similar question has already been answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/73084/what-characters-should-i-use-or-not-use-in-usernames-on-linux/73101#73101)

Theoretically you can use almost any ASCII character you want as username, but, to avoid some kind of bugs, like to one mentioned in the above article, you can set that regular expression that avoid certain issues.

Comment: You won't be able to use `:`, a newline or a null character in a user name even if you edit `/etc/passwd` (or most other user databases) by hand.

Comment: @Gilles yes you right, I corrected the answer, but the underscore is fine, to answer to the question the NAME_REGEX is there to prevent some kind of bugs, but it's not set as default because normally some of these chars are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Debian Squeeze and I managed to create a user with underscore, `adduser user_1`. Why do you say they are not allowed?

Comment: Maybe I have misinterpreted it. I just remembered editing /etc/adduser.conf on a Debian server and the NAME_REGEX (ie the disallowed name regex) contained an underscore. It was commented there however, but I guess I assumed that it represented the default NAME_REGEX.

Comment: `NAME_REGEX` is the *allowed* name regex, not the *disallowed* name regex... i.e. if a name matches `NAME_REGEX` then it is valid.

Comment: Debian lenny (stable as I write) doesn't have `NAME_REGEX` in `/etc/adduser.conf`, and the built-in default forbids `_`.